# Abbreviations: Count backslash as part of the word

Tags: abbreviations

I am usually writing LaTeX documents. I like to use

```
:iab iso isomorphism
```

so that if I write a sentence like `This map is an iso.`, it will expand to `This map is an isomorphism.`. However, I also quite frequently use the command `\iso` in math mode. So for example, I will write `$f \colon V \iso W$` and nothing should be expanded. In other words, the backslash should be counted like a regular character at the beginning of the word, just as `aiso` would not be expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abbreviations use the `iskeyword` option.  Thus, you can add `\` to the list of keyword characters.

```
set iskeyword+=\
```

However, this has many side effects which might be unwanted, such changing the meaning of motions like `w`.  An alternative is to use an expression abbreviation which checks whether the iso is prefixed with a `\`:

```
inoreabbrev <expr> iso getline('.')[col('.')-5] == '\' ? 'iso' : 'isomorphism'
```

Thus, `\iso` will stay as `\iso` but `iso` will be expanded to `isomorphism`.